# How can I do auto-completion of text in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

How can I do auto-completion of text in the Dymola model editor?  Also, same question for the command prompt.

Comment: Here is a list of keyboard shortcuts in Dymola: http://www.claytex.com/blog/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-and-commands/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the editor, start typing then hit Ctrl + space.

I don't know about the command prompt.

/Rene

Comment: I got no response when hit Ctrl+Space, is this hotkey is customized? How could I check the hotkey settings?

Comment: For the auto-complete to work there must be blank space after the cursor

Comment: It turns out the hotkey of switching input method takes up Ctrl+Space. After I modified the setting in the input method, auto-completion works fine in dymola.