# Text auto-format command/shortcut in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a auto-format command/short-cut in the Dymola text editor that will take care of the proper tab spacing?

**Example:**

Original

```
model test
    Real tabCorrecet;
        Real tabIncorrect;
equation
    for i in 1:m loop
ImTabbedWrong=moveMe;
        end for; //me too!!!
end test;
```

Fixed via One Button Click/hotkey

```
model test
    Real tabCorrecet;
    Real tabIncorrect;
equation
    for i in 1:m loop
        ImTabbedWrong=moveMe;
    end for; //me too!!!
end test;
```

Comment: Claytex has a list of useful Dymola Keyboard shortcuts: http://www.claytex.com/blog/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-and-commands/

Comment: @matth, the auto-complete command doesn't work on Dymola, how could I customize this hotkey?

Comment: Autocomplete works for me, in all Dymola versions. What version are you using? Also see this relatedquestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973514/how-can-i-do-auto-completion-of-text-in-dymola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight what you want formatted, or `ctrl+A` for the entire file, and then press `ctrl+shift+L` or right click and select `Reformat Selection`.